# Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hbm2ddl

In my spring mvc app, i have the following object. I am trying to make a visual of data using `devtool` in my app.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ConsultationRequest {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String purpose;

    private String programme;

    private int year;

    private String language;

    private String comments;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ConsultationStatus status;
}
```

Then i used the jpa to make the entity:

```
@Repository
public interface ConsultationRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<ConsultationRequest, Long> {

}
```

The problem is when i load my application, i face with 2 errors:

```
 Unsuccessful: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
[36morg.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
```

Then when i open the

```
http://localhost:8080/h2-console/
```

I cannot see the table.
It seems that the in the boot process, table is not made.

Answer (score 96):

Update your code as below:

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
```

As you have not specified a sequence **table name**, hibernate will look for a sequence table named as **hibernate_sequence** and use it as **default**.

For Oracle/Postgres, increment fields used are sequence tables.
In MySql, there are increment fields that automatically increment.

Answer (score 28):

If someone is getting this error with **Spring Boot testing(with H2)** , we have to use following in the application.properties(or whatever profile we are using) :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Comment: I actually use the property: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update. That doesn't override the data in case they were inserted with non-generated keys in data.sql

Comment: `create-drop` worked for POSTing data but not for loading from `data.sql` during startup with H2 database.  The `update` value worked the opposite (worked fro data.sql but not for POST data) and the `none` value was the same as `update`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Setting the following property in the properties file helped me solve the `hibernate_sequence` problem for hibernate 5.4v

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
```

Comment: I had already wasted half a day on this, and tried everything. Nothing worked, until I have found this solution.
When testing my DB Code, I use Liquibase to create the DB schema, and populate it with some data. 


In my tests, I was always getting this error:
`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement`


This was the fix:
`spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false`

Comment: This also was the solution for me.  I use liquibase as well to create the database tables with an intended target of PostgreSQL, and H2 for testing.  The auto-increment works in PostgreSQL by creating a sequence, but not in H2.  This was the solution for me, as the H2 db is not persistent and I just need a new next sequence ID for testing.

Answer (score 8):

Check `persistence.xml`

```
property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"
```

not `hdm2ddl`

This worked in my case.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a 2nd cache with liquidbase, you have to add the sequence in the changelog like this:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs"
    id="createSequence-example">
    <createSequence catalogName="cat" cycle="false"
        incrementBy="1" ordered="true" schemaName="public"
        sequenceName="hibernate_sequence" startValue="0" />
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 3):

> SQL operation ERROR when start app spring-boot.

I added the setting in spring properties and solved: in the spring:jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop to hibernate be able create or drop table automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

`spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false` is no longer supported,
use this instead

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=legacy
```

Answer (score 0):

For `spring-boot` `2.7.x` and `h2` `2.x` you need to add `MODE=LEGACY;` in the database connection:

example application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=LEGACY;
```

exemple application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=LEGACY;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while running some tests. Adding these annotations helped me fix the issue for me:

```java
@Transactional
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
```

Answer (score -1):

If someone is having this problem while testing a repository, changing the code like below might help you:

### From this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

### To this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

with

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
```

in test-config.properties works for me

Answer (score -2):

For Mysql:

the auto-increment is not added, modify ur table:

ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT=1