# Spring boot can not find HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

For many applications all we will need is to put the right Spring 
Data dependencies on the classpath.it works fine :

config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"io.boot.spring.entities"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"io.boot.spring.repositories"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ConfigForJPA {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari")
public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
    return (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}
```

}

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
spring.datasource.hikari.username=sa
spring.datasource.hikari.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
```

console:

```
Hibernate: drop table Blog if exists
Hibernate: drop table Item if exists
Hibernate: drop table Role if exists
Hibernate: drop table User if exists
Hibernate: drop table User_roles if exists
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: create table Blog 
Hibernate: create table Item 
Hibernate: create table Role 
Hibernate: create table User 
Hibernate: create table User_roles (users_id integer not null, roles_id integer not null)
main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into Role (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into Role (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into User (email, name, password, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into User_roles (users_id, roles_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into User_roles (users_id, roles_id) values (?, ?)
```

but Spring boot doc says to take full control of the configuration of the 
EntityManagerFactory, you need to add a @Bean named ‘entityManagerFactory’
and when I add it to my config.

config:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
    entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages("io.boot.spring")
                .persistenceUnit("io.boot.spring.entities")
                .build();

    }
```

It gives the error:

console:

```
: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Started.
: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory
 for persistence unit 'io.boot.spring.entities'
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
: SQL Error: 90036, SQLState: 90036
: Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
call next value for hibernate_sequence [90036-193]
```

why HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE not found? I did not modify anything
just added the entityManagerFactory bean to config file

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    ... getters and setters
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequence "HIBERNATE\_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807483/sequence-hibernate-sequence-not-found-sql-statement)

Comment: no my case is different

Comment: in my code (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) is already included
I posted one of my entities

Comment: You're not using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` but `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` though.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT(
  ID            INTEGER         NOT NULL,
  CLIENT_NAME   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
  ACTIVE        CHAR(1)         NOT NULL  DEFAULT 'Y'
);

 CREATE SEQUENCE CLIENT_SEQUENCE_ID START WITH (select max(ID) + 1 from CLIENT);
```

(this allows you to prepopulate the CLIENT with static values, and initialize the sequence accordingly)

and in Java

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name= "CLIENT_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "CLIENT_SEQUENCE_ID", initialValue=1, allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="CLIENT_SEQUENCE")
private Long id
```

;

please follow the above instruction.