# How to save an Entity object into an initialized h2 table with generated index?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a spring boot project with a h2 database. A table `debug` is initialized from `schema.sql`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS debug;
  
CREATE TABLE debug (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  dummycol VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);
```

`data.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO debug (id, dummycol) VALUES
  (0, 'foo'), 
  (1, 'ba');
```

For that to work I have to put `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` in application.properties. According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) this is neccessary for `schema.sql` but I found that with another value such as `create-drop` while the schema is generated (I assume from the annotated classes) the loading script `data.sql` is ignored so the tables are empty after startup.

I define an Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "debug")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DebugE {

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="dummycol")
    private String dummy;
}
```

Then, I subclass `CrudRepository`: `public interface DebugRepository extends CrudRepository<DebugE, Long>` and add an entity object to the table

```
@Autowired
DebugRepository cr;
...
    DebugE d = new DebugE();
    d.setId(computeFreeId(cr))
    d.setDummy("foo1");
    cr.save(d);
```

So far everything works, but now I would like to `id` to be set automatically.
For that I add `@GeneratedValue` to the class and comment out `d.setId` because I expect the framework to do that for me. I have no preference towards a `GenerationType`, so far neither works:
`AUTO`,`SEQUENCE`:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90036, SQLState: 90036
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
call next value for hibernate_sequence [90036-200]
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [call next value for hibernate_sequence]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
call next value for hibernate_sequence [90036-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:576) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
```

`IDENTITY`:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into debug (id, dummycol) values (null, ?) [23502-200]
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into debug (id, dummycol) values (null, ?) [23502-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
```

`TABLE`:

```
 o.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator   : HHH000351: Could not read or init a hi value

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCES" not found; SQL statement:
select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
```

## Attempts based on other questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39094773
  `strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY` and adding `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` to `application.properties`.
  Gives a warning: `'hibernate.dialect' is an unknown property.` and no change in error message
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63775719/3014199
  adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false`
  No change for `IDENTITY`,`SEQUENCE`.
  Similar error for `TABLE`:

```
org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000015: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator] table-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCES" not found; SQL statement:
select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences where sequence_name = 'debug' for update [42102-200]
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63127119/3014199
  Setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` from `none` to `create-drop` works(i.e. ids are generated, rows are added to table) but now the table is no longer initialized from `data.sql`.

## additional details

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:h2db
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.2.1"
}


group = 'com.my.project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
}
```

## Solution

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` in application.properties
`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` in the class and
`id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` in schema.sql made it work.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml and application.properties files?

Comment: @Rodrigo I've added my application.properties and build.gradle.

Comment: I reproduced your error setting the 'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property' to none. Maybe this property has been overwrited by some profile configuration or by command line.

Comment: have you tried without any spring or hibernate settings? I thing spring boot uses an in memory database by default if no configuration is found. schema.sql and data.sql is picked up automatically also from classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate the id and at the same time using *sql files, you need define the auto_increment property to your id field in creation table.

Because when you using generation strategy - Identity, hibernate believes that your columns is auto increments on a table side.