# hibernate auto generated sequence on non primary key field

Tags: java, hibernate

I was using `hibernate 5.5` + `postgresql 13`

I want to have auto generated sequence field (**auto gen on database side instead of java side**), which is equivalent to this DDL in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE map_objects (
        oid BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, 
        vid BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, 
        msg VARCHAR, 
        PRIMARY KEY (vid)
);
```

as you can see in the DDL, both `vid` and `oid` is auto gen in db side, however `vid` is `pk` but `oid` is not

after I run this plain DDL sql in psql, I got 1 table and 2 sequences, the 2 sequences are used to generate default values for `vid` and `oid`

```
                                  Table "public.map_objects"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                  
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 oid    | bigint            |           | not null | nextval('map_objects_oid_seq'::regclass)
 vid    | bigint            |           | not null | nextval('map_objects_vid_seq'::regclass)
 msg    | character varying |           |          |
```

I want to have a equivalent definition in hibernate entity declaration, here is what I've tried:

```
@Entity
public class MapObject {
    @Id
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long vid;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    private Long oid;

    private String msg;

}
```

the `vid` is good, but the `oid` is not working in the way I expected, it was inserting `null` value for `oid`, not even having an auto-gen value in java side.

try2: `GenerateType.SEQUENCE`, but no luck.

try3:

```
    @Column(name = "oid", columnDefinition = "BIGSERIAL", nullable = true)
    private Long oid;
```

this approach basically manually define the column and the ORM know nothing about the entity, so after I insert the object, hibernate won't populate the generated `oid` from db, it's still null in Java side, therefore this is still not my expected behavior....

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60216566/6277104) will be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at my response on hibernate_sequence auto increment for different databases https://stackoverflow.com/a/39808110/6813506